# Avoid XSS with BBCode input and HTML output

Tags: html, codeigniter, xss, bbcode, htmlspecialchars

I'm currently working on a website, where users can write articles with few format possibilities (like bold, italic, list...). I'm using a framework: CodeIgniter.

I'm a beginner, and I've heard some stuff about XSS. I would like to know what do you think about my implementation. I read this topic:
[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130323#130323)

1) The user write his article, format it with BBCode. I'm using SCEditor.

2) When saving it into database, I'm using htmlspecialchars() to filter any suspect HTML tag. Am I supposed to do this when I'm saving data, or displaying data?

3) When I want to display the article on the website (for other uses for example), I convert BBCode tags into HTML tags.

Is it a right way to do it? Am I avoiding XSS?

I am obviously open to suggestions and advices.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter for validation has a property xss which will do all those staff

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
```

check out form validation Codeigniter:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: I saw that, but according to this topic, it is not enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337143/codeigniter-why-use-xss-clean

Answer (score 2):

I "find and replace" using PHP, I don't think it's the most efficient way of doing it though.

```
<?php
    $malicious = "<script>alert(1)</script>";
    $malicious = str_ireplace("<", "", $malicious);
    $malicious = str_ireplace(">", "", $malicious);
    echo $malicious;
?>
```

Comment: I'm aware that this question is old, but it gets quite a few views, so I thought about commenting this answer. It's actually a bad way to do that, you could for example still put XSS in an onload-attribute or something similar.

Comment: Alongside @1n9i9c7om, I would like to point out that with this method the user cannot insert the `<` or `>` sign which can be quite annoying. Instead of deleting the character, you could instead replace it with the corresponding HTML entity: `&lt;` or `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$malicious = "<script>alert(1)</script>";
$malicious = strip_tags($malicious);
$malicious = htmlentities($malicious, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $malicious;
?>
```