# Codeigniter XSS filter not working for image injection?

Tags: codeigniter

Newbie to CI, trying to avoid some code injection in the input field.

In my Login text I input the name, with one image `<img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/markiplier/images/a/a4/EvilGame.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20151015031339" >` followed.
I tried:

1. Setting the global_xss_filtering `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`
2. `$login=$this->input->post('login', TRUE);`
3. `$login = $this->security->xss_clean($login);`

However, non of the above can ease the image when I echo $login. Do I implement the XSS filter correctly? Or I misunderstand the usage of CI XSS filter?

Answer (score 0):

`xss_clean()` is for filtering output only (and does nothing for input) and`global_xss_filtering` has been deprecated. [Apparently xss_clean was laughably bad in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337143/codeigniter-why-use-xss-clean). I don't know if it's been through a rewrite.

This talks about input validation

http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Input-Validation.html

Also this (useful, but dated)

[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php?rq=1)

This talks about XSS prevention. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

This on XSS too.

https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know

Comment: @ourmandave- Many thanks. I am just curious about the CI XSS filter. And your materials are helpful.