# Escape html all posted values

Tags: codeigniter, html-escape

why `$this->input->post(NULL,TRUE)` don't escape html tags ?
is there any hook to replace `<` character with empty in codeigniter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - why use xss\_clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337143/codeigniter-why-use-xss-clean)

Comment: no it's not duplicate.how to escape html using this function?