# Some text was removed while xss filtering in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, input, xss

Removed text is '% 33', '% 40'. (single quote is not included)

```
$text = "% 33";
$xss_text = $this->input->post($text, TRUE);
echo $xss_text;
// result is 3 and @
```

Comment: so don't use xss filtering.. it isn't useful in most circumstances anyways. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337143/codeigniter-why-use-xss-clean

Comment: Thanks Alex, i should remove the method